# object HTMLImageElement popping in jQuery funtion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 images displayed on a page. I want a message to appear when I click 1 image and it to disappear when I click the alternate one, then vice versa.

The jQuery code I created below seems to be working fine, but I am continuously getting an [object HTMLImageElement] message on the alternate image every time I click the one that is displaying the text.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#gimp").click(function(){
    var gimp = "Gimp message.";
    var i = $("#qInkscape").text(inkscape);
      if (i == true) {
        $("#qInkscape").hide();
        $("#qGimp").text(gimp);
     } else {
        $("#qGimp").text(gimp);
     }
  });
    $("#inkscape").click(function(){
    var inkscape = "Inkscape message";
    var g = $("#qGimp").text(gimp);
      if (g == true) {
        $("#qGimp").hide();
        $("#qInkscape").text(inkscape); 
      } else {
      $("#qInkscape").text(inkscape);
      }      
  });
});
```

And the html

```
<div class="mf-container">
  <div class="mf-content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="mf-third mf-center">
        <img src="img/qualifications/gimp_g.png" class="mf-pic-unique mf-pic-
          shadow mf-margin-top" id="gimp" alt="about gimp">
        <p id="qGimp" class="mf-off-black-text"> </p>
      </div>
      <div class="mf-third mf-margin-top">
        <p class="mf-center mf-off-black-text">Click on an image to learn more 
          about each technology</p>
      </div>
      <div class="mf-third mf-center">
        <img src="img/qualifications/inkscape_G.png" class="mf-pic-unique mf-
          pic-shadow mf-margin-top" id="inkscape" alt="about inkscape">
        <p id="qInkscape" class="mf-off-black-text"> </p>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `html` needed..

Comment: `var i = $("#qInkscape").text(inkscape);` and `var g = $("#qGimp").text(gimp);`. Where both of these lines are executed, there is no such `inkscape` nor `gimp` variable defined. And because you have elements with `id` set to `"inkscape"`  and `"gimp"`, these variables are automatically mapped to these elements.

Comment: In your script I did not found anything wrong. May be effected by other script. jsFiddle will be nice for trace the fact.